# How to maintain uniqueness during SQL Join within Access-VBA function?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I currently have the following Access VBA function:

```
Private Function MapFields(tableNameTemp As String, tableName As String, commonField As String, newTableName)

    sqlJoinQuery = "SELECT [" + tableNameTemp + "].[Field1], " & _
                   "[" + tableNameTemp + "].[Field2], " & _
                   "[" + tableNameTemp + "].[Field3], " & _
                   "[" + tableNameTemp + "].[Field4], " & _
                   "[" + tableName + "].*" & _
                   " INTO " + newTableName & _
                   " FROM [" + tableNameTemp & _
                   "] INNER JOIN [" + tableName & _
                   "] ON [" + tableNameTemp + "].[" + commonField + "] = [" + tableName + "].[" + commonField + "];"
    Debug.Print sqlJoinQuery
    CurrentDb.Execute sqlJoinQuery

End Function
```

What this is doing is taking the `tableName` table and inner joining with the `newTableName` table's `Field1` to `Field4` on `commonField`.  Note that `Field4` will be the same as `commonField`, since it needs to be selected to perform the join.

In order to convey my intended behavior, I must explain how `tableNameTemp`'s fields are structured.  The table immediately below is an example of some of the fields that will be pulled from `tableNameTemp`, as they would appear in the `tableNameTemp` table.

```
╔════════════════════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ Field4 AKA commonField ║ Field1 ║ Field2 ║ Field3 ║
╠════════════════════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  SA12                  ║  No    ║  No    ║  No    ║
╠════════════════════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  CY84                  ║  No    ║  No    ║  No    ║
╠════════════════════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  CY84                  ║  Yes   ║  No    ║  No    ║
╠════════════════════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  CY84                  ║  No    ║  No    ║  Yes   ║
╠════════════════════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  CY84                  ║  No    ║  Yes   ║  No    ║
╠════════════════════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  EH09                  ║  Yes   ║  No    ║  No    ║
╠════════════════════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  EH09                  ║  No    ║  No    ║  No    ║
╚════════════════════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

As you can see above, the `tableNameTemp` table does not have unique commonField/Field4 values.  However, the table which it will be joined with, `tableName`, *does* have unique commonField/Field4 values.  What I intend to do is make it so that for each field in `Field1` - `Field3`,  if any of the records have a `yes`, then map a `yes` onto the same field in the related record in `tableName`.  That way, `tableName` can maintain the uniqueness of it's `commonField`.  How might I be able to achieve this?

So, given the example `tableNameTemp` values in the table above, the table below shows how those values would be mapped onto the `tableName` table

```
╔════════════════════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ Field4 AKA commonField ║ Field1 ║ Field2 ║ Field3 ║
╠════════════════════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  SA12                  ║  No    ║  No    ║  No    ║
╠════════════════════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  CY84                  ║  Yes   ║  Yes   ║  Yes   ║
╠════════════════════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  EH09                  ║  Yes   ║  No    ║  No    ║
╚════════════════════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Note that there is no primary key in either of the tables and `Field1` -`Field4` are not the only fields in both `tableName` and `tableNameTemp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering if you have all other fields besides field1-4 to have values YES or NO. But, from the dataset above you can try this.

```
 sqlJoinQuery = 
    "SELECT tbl_grp_by.*, [" + tableName + "].* " & _
    "INTO " + newTableName & _
    " FROM (SELECT Max([" + tableNameTemp + "].[Field1]) as Field1, " & _
    "Max([" + tableNameTemp + "].[Field2]) as Field2, " & _
    "Max([" + tableNameTemp + "].[Field3]) as Field3, " & _
    "[" + tableNameTemp + "].[Field4] as Field4 " & _
    "FROM [" + tableNameTemp & _
    "] INNER JOIN [" + tableName & _
    "] ON [" + tableNameTemp + "].[" + commonField + "] = [" + tableName + "].[" + commonField + "] " & _
    "GROUP BY [" + tableNameTemp + "].[" + commonField + "]) as tbl_grp_by " &  _
    "INNER JOIN [" + tableName & _
    "] ON [" + tableName + "].[" + commonField + "] = tbl_grp_by.[" + commonField + "]"
```

Comment: One of the fields does have text values in which there is a predefined hierarchy, but I did not mention this to over-complicate the question.  I figured that I would bring it up in another question if need-be.  Also, thank you for your answer - I will give it a try!

Comment: When I run this, after removing the unnecessary quote after `GROUP BY`, I get the following error:  `Run-time erorr '3120':  Cannot group on fields selected with "*"`

Comment: Edit: This still happens even when I remove the GROUP BY tag.

Comment: sorry, i havent notice that you are also trying to pull the records from `tableName`. You have to put all the other fields missing  both on  SELECT and GROUP BY clause from `tableName`

Comment: Do you mean to individually select each field in tableName?

Comment: yes, individual fields. you can also check the update on query i had. It used subquery to get the aggregated  values t.

Comment: I am currently working on  a function that get all of the field names in tableName and turns it into the sql select strings.  Does you updated query already do that?

Comment: The updated query does get the aggregated values from field1-4 group by `commonField` then merged using the SELECT clause to `tableName` fields which is then used to create the new table

Comment: Thanks, do you know why I'm now getting this error: `Run-time error '3067': Query input must contain at least one table or query`

Comment: I missed the space from `"INTO " + newTableName & _
    "FROM`. it should be `"INTO " + newTableName & _
    " FROM`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120715/discussion-between-winghei-and-paradox).

Comment: winghei: Unfortunately, my internet is filtered (not by me), so I cannot use the chat function of this site.

Comment: Please check the space before FROM after INTO clause. It should work fine.

Comment: I have posted a [continuation of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903010/how-to-sql-join-tables-selecting-the-largest-value-in-access-vba-function) involving values other than (yes, no) if you are interested.  Your previous solution worked very well, thank you.